# C Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error in code

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve a problem :

The task is -

Given an array of strings sorted in lexicographical order, print all of its permutations in strict lexicographical order. If two permutations look the same, only print one of them. See the 'note' below for an example.

Complete the function next_permutation which generates the permutations in the described order.

For example, The six permutations in the correct order are:

ab bc cd
ab cd bc
bc ab cd
bc cd ab
cd ab bc
cd bc ab

Note: There may be two or more of the same string as elements of s.

For example,s = [ab,ab,bc] . Only one instance of a permutation where all elements match should be printed. In other words, ifs[0] == s[1](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4FC5FfU) , then print either s[0] s[1](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4FC5FfU) or s[1](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4FC5FfU) s[0] but not both.

A three element array having three discrete elements has six permutations as shown above. In this case, there are three matching pairs of permutations wheres[0] = ab and s[1](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4FC5FfU) = ab are switched. We only print the three visibly unique permutations:

ab ab bc
ab bc ab
bc ab ab

Input Format

The first line of each test file contains a single integer n, the length of the string array s.

Each of the next n lines contains a string s[i].

Sample Input 0

2
ab
cd

Sample Output 0

ab cd
cd ab

And [this](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4FC5FfU) is the code I wrote.

But I'm getting segmentation fault (core dumped) error

As per my knowledge segmentation fault is encountered when we access something which no longer exists.  But I don't think I'm doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: Please put everything directly in your post

Comment: Please take some time to read about (or refresh) [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please create a [mcve] to show us in the question itself.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger? By using a debugger you can catch the crash as it happens, and will be able to locate when and where in your code it happens. You can also examine variables and see their values at the location of the crash.

Comment: Yep, a segmentation fault isn't just an annoyance, it's an opportunity to find out exactly what happened. You can catch it directly in a debugger, or allow core dumps (with `ulimit -c unlimited` or similar) and examine the core file with your debugger.

Comment: PS. StackOverflow questions are meant to be useful to other people who have the same problem later on. Putting all the code in a link, which may rot and is anyway not directly visible, breaks this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your array run into index out of bounds, the probleme is in the `next_permutation` function.

The error is here:

```
for(int j = i+2; j <= n; j++)
```

The correct is:

```
for(int j = i+2; j < n; j++)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.